# Passing selected radio button value to groovy controller

Tags: grails, groovy, radio-button, radio-group

Unable to obtain value of selected radio button, to the controller class. 
I have a radio-group, to display two radio buttons on a page, as well as an input text field, and a button that validates the input, and takes them to the desired page. 
The idea is that the user can select the radio button, which will in turn determine the action performed on what is inputed into the text field.

However, I am finding it difficult to pass the value of radio button to the controller, based on which radio button has been selected, this will determine how the user input is validated.

Have looked through the grails documentation, as well as through stack-overflow posts, to try and understand how to pass the value of selected to the groovy controller, from my index.gsp class.

index.gsp:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <g:radioGroup name=“Radio" values=“['value1', ‘value2']" value="value1" onchange="setRadio(this)">
          <td> ${it.radio} ${it.label}
          </td>
        </g:radioGroup>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <g:form>
      <table class =“Radiotable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <g:textArea class="smallTextArea" name=“radioVal" value="Paste your input for value1" />
          </td>
        </tr>
          <td>
            <g:actionSubmit value="validate" action="validate" />
      </table>
</g:form>
```

controller:

```
class AesController {

    def index() {


    }
    def validate() {

    }

}
```

onchange=“setRadio(this”>

Changes the text shown in the input field with a JS function. By default it shows "Paste your input for value1”. Currently if the user changes between the two radio button it changes between "Paste your input for value1” and "Paste your input for value2”. The idea is that if they have value1 or value2 selected this will have a different value and different action occurs to the inputted text

I expect the user to be able to select a radio button and this value is passed to the controller so it is know what radio button the user pressed.

Comment: Do you not just need to extend your form to include the radio buttons?

Comment: @MikeW thanks, I have already tried extending it, yet I am still unable to pass the value to the controller

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you to add the radio-button group in the form. However, if this does not work, add a hidden field to your form:

```
<g:hiddenField name="selectedRadioButton" value="value1" />
```

And update it in your setRadio(x) javascript function based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your radio group into . So it will be:

```
<g:form>
...
<g:radioGroup name="Radio" values="['value1', 'value2']" value="value1" onchange="setRadio(this)">
...
<g:textArea class="smallTextArea" name="radioVal" value="Paste your input for value1" />
...
<g:actionSubmit value="validate" action="validate" />
</g:form>
```

Then you can easily access to radio button value by params.Radio